# KnockoutJS remove from JQuery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I would like to use the JQuery mobile listview with popup with Knockout.js
I don't know unfortunately how to refer the correct ID in the popup.

EDIT
An example can be found here http://jsfiddle.net/QQMD5/4/
The functionality itself works but unfortunately not with the popup of jQuery Mobile...

The listview is quite simple now and follows the example on the JQuery Mobile website

```html
<div data-role="content">       
    <ul data-bind="foreach: lines" data-role="listview" data-split-icon="gear" data-split-theme="d" data-inset="true" data-filter="true">
        <li><a href="#">
            <img src="https://adium.im/images/services/icon-msn.png">
            <h2 data-bind="text: ItemCod"></h2>
            <p data-bind="text: ItemName"><strong></strong></p>
            <p></p>
            <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>6:24</strong>PM</p>
            <a href="#purchase" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop">Delete Item</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div data-role="popup" id="purchase" data-theme="d" data-overlay-theme="b" class="ui-content" style="max-width:340px; padding-bottom:2em;">
        <h3>Delete Item?</h3>
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.removeLine" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-theme="b" data-icon="check" data-inline="true" data-mini="true">Buy: $10.99</a>
        <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-inline="true" data-mini="true">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

While the KnockoutJS part is now only client-side as

```
self.removeLine = function(line) { self.lines.remove(line); }
```

I imagine the point here is that it doesn't recognize the correct line to be picked.

Thank you

Comment: Where are you calling removeLine() from?

Comment: small typo, see update code. Sorry!

Comment: How does the popup get it's value?

Comment: I have two observations 1) don't use `.ready()` in jQM, its' equivalent is `pageinit` or use other jQM events. 2) page div should be the direct parent of popup div. edit your fiddle, you're loading jquery 1.10 and 1.9

Comment: Omar, is this correct in terms of pageinit? Thx http://jsfiddle.net/QQMD5/6/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UPyUW/1/ wrap code in <head>, it's working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems I see in your code which may be copy paste errors or may be breaking your stuff -

You open the anchor tag but never close it

```
<li>
    <a href="#">
        <img src="https://adium.im/images/services/icon-msn.png">
        <h2 data-bind="text: ItemCod"></h2>
        <p data-bind="text: ItemName"><strong></strong></p>
        <p></p>
        <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>6:24</strong>PM</p>
        <button data-bind="click: setItemToRemove">Delete Item</button>
    </a>
</li>
```

And if you are going to set an item to be deleted, pass that item into an observable and that way when you call removeLine it passes the proper object back to the view model to remove -

```
self.itemToRemove = ko.observable();
self.setItemToRemove = function(line) { self.itemToRemove(line); }
self.removeLine = function(line) { self.lines.remove(line); }
```

And make your pop or w/e display only when itemToRemove has a value -

```
<div data-role="popup" data-bind="with: itemToRemove">
    <h3>Delete Item?</h3>
    <button href="#" data-bind="click: $root.removeLine" >Buy: $10.99</button>
    <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-inline="true" data-mini="true">Cancel</a>
</div>
```

**Updated**

You had a bunch of syntax errors in your fiddle -

http://jsfiddle.net/QQMD5/3/

Comment: To be completely strict: Being an inline element itself, `<a>` may not contain block elements like `<h3>` or `<p>`.

Comment: PW Kad by doing this I have an error on the Knockout.JS library GetBindings. It seems to happen when I load data, because the list is now composed of 2 elements and stops at the first one.

Comment: It's not too much data - there is something else going on.  This will work as shown, if you don't think so create a small jsFiddle reproducing the issue.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QQMD5/1 but there is still a small error on JSON data as it doesn't load. Thank you!

Comment: And you are referencing your OrderLineViewModel before it has been evaluated, since it is a function that is evaluated at run-time and throws an error.  Your jsFiddle is full of errors : )

Comment: Apperently the issue is making the popup working with KnockoutJS... http://jsfiddle.net/QQMD5/4/

Comment: I answered your original question and have gone above and beyond to get you your answer, if you can't show a pop-up because some other tools you are using you should probably mark this resolved and create a new question...

Comment: Dear PW Kad, I have got a tons of answers not marked with 10 points and with good explanation. I am here willing to solve my issue and marking yours as the best one. My question was the interaction between a ListView in JQuery Mobile and the KnockoutJS. I am trying to sort it out and I think that it could be of general interest. I appreciate your effort.

Comment: Dear @Mauro - 99% of your problems are syntax related, meaning you don't understand basic JavaScript usage therefore your problem is not repeatable.  In those instances it is impossible to keep fixing problems for someone because they don't actually know what is wrong.  If the issue is that you can show a popup until you use Knockout bindings, then at least produce a fiddle showing that - as it stood, your fiddles had basic JavaScript errors and wouldn't show anything, so it's no wonder I couldn't figure out what the problem was...

Comment: Fair enough. Someone in a comment pointed out a couple of good points. If Omar decides to go for the solution it will the best otherwise yours will be flagged as best. Thanks for spotting some of the issues. I mean it, thank you, I don't know why you took it so seriously and personal :)
BTW, I do understand Javascript

Comment: No one took anything serious nor personal - your specific question will further confuse future visitors who are coming here looking for an answer because of basic syntax errors and assumptions that you posted, such as using too much data, the problem is with knockout, etc...  You're creating a bad rap for Knockout